# What is a better way to display data from multiple view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two view models

```
public class DataImportViewModel
{
    public WccrViewModel wccrVM { get; set; }
    public string Status                { get; set; }
    public string ValidationResult      { get; set; }
    …
 }

public class WccrViewModel
{
    public double? WccrId  { get; set; }
    public string WccrDesc { get; set; }
}
```

and my view

```
@model List<Mass.ViewModels.DataImportViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Validation", "DataImport", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<input id="ProcessReshop" type="submit" value="Reshop" />

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model[i].wccrVM.WccrId)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].wccrVM.WccrId)
    </div>
            }
```

A table (not shown) is populated with the DataImportViewModel. I want to have the WccrViewModel displayed on top of the Table. I want to be able to access the WccrViewModel without the for loop...but it shows as a good example. How can I use wccrVM.WccrId without the for loop? Thanks in advance...cheers

Comment: You're not very clear. You don't have a table just divs. Why do you want to access `WccrViewModel` without `for`?

Comment: model is `List<DataImportViewModel>`, so you are going to have `WccrViewModel` in every item in `List<DataImportViewModel`, Can you be little more specific?

Comment: Right Pravin, and I guess what I need to think about is using a partial for the WccrViewModel to display it separately rather than adding it to the DataImportViewModel. Guess I wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about another viewmodel class that contains both a DataImportViewModel and a WccrViewModel?

Your viewmodel should be tailored to the view, and if the view calls for both those objects, why not create a view model with what it expects?